# Is a t-test and f-test appropriate?

Tags: t-test

I have a query about which t-test is appropriate (paired or unequal variance)?

I have calculated the returns of two different stock portfolios. Here is a sample of my (full sample Jan 1990 to Dec 2017):

```
             Date        Hedged Portfolio Unhedge_Portfolio 
             Jan 1990         1.24           1.27
             Feb 1990         1.23           1.26
             Mar 1990         1.27           1.23
             Apr 1990         1.25           1.29
```

To test whether the returns are statistically different from each other, is the appropriate test, paired or unequal variance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A t-test is best

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt - Thank you. In this case, is the t-test a paired t-test or an unequal variance t-test? Sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: Neither test makes sense to me since returns are not independent over time. (As a general principle, be cautious of answers which don't give reasoning for one choice over another.)

Comment: As @Glen_b said, you don't want any t test.  You need to account for the serial autocorrelation in the data.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, 'none of the above' should always be a choice.

Comment: My concern was not so much with serial correlation in returns (there's usually not a lot of it, though there can be periods with some) as it was with heteroskedasticity (which is why people look at ARCH/GARCH and more complicated models), which is often substantial. It's still a form of dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Although t-tests allow testing of mean differences in two samples, an assumption of this statistic is that measurements are independent. Sometimes this is violated in a one-sample pre-test/post-test research design where the two sets of measurements come from the same sample of individuals. This sort of violation can be corrected for with paired samples t-tests, as you mentioned in your comment. However, another type of violation of the independence assumption is called autocorrelation. In your example, a lag-1 autocorrelation would measure the association between returns in one month and the month before it, or in other words it would be a correlation between the data for (Feb, Mar, Apr) and (Jan, Feb, Mar).

To control for autocorrelation violating the assumption of independence, first calculate the autocorrelation coefficient at n/4 lags or, because your measures are monthly, up to 12 lags (which is your frequency) (cf. Cowpertwait and Metcalfe, 2009). If the autocorrelation coefficient is not statistically significant, then a t-test may be appropriate. However, if the correlation coefficient is statistically significant, then you must alter your statistical test.

Rather than use a t-test, it might be useful to use a regression formula. Regression covers all multivariate analyses (Cohen, 1968). For example, rather than testing the null hypothesis $$H_0: \bar{x_1}\ne \bar{x_2}$$ where `x_1={1.24,1.23,1.27,1.25...}` and `x_2={1.27,1.26,1.23,1.29,...}` you would instead create a categorical variable `y`, where $$y={0,0,0,0,...,1,1,1,1,...}$$ Then, use a regression formula: $$y=\beta(x)+e$$ In this formula,`Beta` is a slope coefficient,  `x` is a concatenation of `x1` and `x2`, and `e` is an error term.

Finally, to control for autocorrelation, include an autoregressive coefficient in your regression formula, such that $$y_t=\beta(x)+\phi_k(y_{t-1})+e$$ In this formula, `phi` is an autoregressive coefficient and `k` is the statistically significant lag.

For even small levels of autocorrelation, whether it's statistically significant or not, there is an inflated type-I error (Scheffe, 1959). For example, with 365 repeated measures at autoregression of 0.4, the type-I error rate can be as high as 17% (Raadt, 2018).